# ¿Cómo puedo crear una columna con los mismo valores que otra columna pero ubicados una fila más abajo?

Tags: base-de-datos, r

mi df se ve así:

```
Cuenta_Vig     Cuenta_Def
     2             0
   616             3
   116             2
    75             0
    .              .
    .              .
    .              .
    43             3
    30             1
    21             3
    14             1
    10             2
```

Quisiera crear dos columnas adicionales que tengan los mismos valores que esas columnas, pero que empiecen una fila más abajo y que el último valor (es decir, la última fila de mi df) sea el penúltimo valor las anteriores columnas, de la siguiente manera:

```
Cuenta_Vig     Cuenta_Def      Resta_Vig      Resta_Def
     2             0               NA             NA
   616             3                2              0
   116             2               616             3 
    75             0               116             2
    .              .                75             0  
    .              .                 .             .
    .              .                 .             .
    43             3                 .             .
    30             1                43             3
    21             3                30             1
    14             1                21             3     
    10             2                14             1
```

Es una base de aproximadamente 700 datos. Intenté encontrar la solución pero en ninguna otra pregutna lo vi, soy bastante nueva en R. Gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es muy fácil usando la función `lag()` de la librería `dplyr`. Esa función "atrasa" a un vector n posiciones, por defecto 1.

```
read.table(
text ="Cuenta_Vig     Cuenta_Def
2             0
616           3
116           2
75            0
43            3
30            1
21            3
14            1
10            2", 
header = T) -> df

library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(Resta_Vig = lag(Cuenta_Vig), 
         Resta_def = lag(Cuenta_Def))
```

Si prefieres no usar librerías aparte puede usar `head(-1)`

```
df$Resta_Vig <- c(NA, head(df$Cuenta_Vig, -1))
```

Y adaptarlo para el otro vector. Tienes que agregar el `NA` del principio "a mano", pero funciona sin dependencias de librerías.

Answer (score 1):

Para desplazar un vector o columna podrías hacer algo como esto: `c(NA, head(<columna>,-<desplazamiento>))`, por ejemplo:

```
Cuenta_Vig <- runif(10)

Resta_Vig <- c(NA, head(Cuenta_Vig,-1))

# Solo para comparar
cbind(Cuenta_Vig, Resta_Vig)

      Cuenta_Vig Resta_Vig
 [1,]  0.5213272        NA
 [2,]  0.2842258 0.5213272
 [3,]  0.1780841 0.2842258
 [4,]  0.1072165 0.1780841
 [5,]  0.3365139 0.1072165
 [6,]  0.2753349 0.3365139
 [7,]  0.2697502 0.2753349
 [8,]  0.2271241 0.2697502
 [9,]  0.2213085 0.2271241
[10,]  0.4237836 0.2213085
```

Y podemos generalizar una función sencilla:

```
pad <- function(x, n) {
  if (n==0) return(x)
  if(n<0) {
    c(rep(NA, abs(n)),head(x, n))
  } else {
    c(tail(x, -n), rep(NA, abs(n)))
  }
}
```

Para poder desplazar hacia una dirección u otra:

```
pad(Cuenta_Vig, -1)
pad(Cuenta_Vig, 1)
```